# How to load and unload linux drivers that are built into kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, kernel-module

I want to load and unload linux drivers in the device terminal,and I have two options but I do not want to do the first one

1. Build driver as a module
   CONFIG_DRIVER = m
   and I can use rmmod and modprobe to unload and load device driver.
2. Build device driver into kernel itself
   CONFIG_DRIVER = Y

I want to follow the 2nd option but I do not know how to unload and load the device driver, can the open source community please help me out here !

Comment: How would you remove something that's not built as removable module? Also, this sounds like an "XY problem" (research that term!) so it may be the wrong question you're asking.

Comment: If the device driver is built into the kernel , is there a way we can stop and restart it's working?

Comment: you can reboot.   You realize that you can build as a module for debug and built-in for release.

Comment: If there's a way within the power cycle ,where I can unload and load device driver when its built into kernel ?

Comment: You cannot load and unload built-in device drivers, but you can "unbind" devices that are being used by drivers, and then "bind" them again afterwards. (In other words, you can cause the driver's "remove" and "probe" handlers to be called for a device.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy as that. You find a device and driver which you want to unbind. For example, on my Intel Minnownboard (v1) I have PCH UDC controller (a PCI device):

```sh
% lspci -nk
...
02:02.4 0c03: 8086:8808 (rev 02)
        Subsystem: 1cc8:0001
        Kernel driver in use: pch_udc
```

Now I know necessary bits:

- bus on which the device is located: **PCI**
- device name: **0000:02:02.4** (note that `lspci` gives reduced PCI address, i.e. without domain or i.o.w. *BDF*, while driver expects *domain:BDF*)
- driver name: **pch_udc**

Take altogether we can unbind the device:

```sh
% echo 0000:02:02.4 > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/pch_udc/unbind
[ 3042.531872] configfs-gadget 0000:02:02.4: unregistering UDC driver [g1]
[ 3042.540979] udc 0000:02:02.4: releasing '0000:02:02.4'
```

You may bind it again. Simple use *bind* node in the same folder.

The feature appeared more than 15 years ago and here is [the article](https://lwn.net/Articles/143397/) on LWN that explains it.